# create a route with vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some issues creating a router using router on vuejs. My file main.js was just like the code below and then when I changed to add some routes I got the error below

MAIN.JS BEFORE (WORKING WELL)

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
    
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from './store'
    
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

MAIN.JS AFTER

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from './store'

import testeRouter from './pages/testeRouter'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
    routers: [
        {
            path: '/pages/testeRouter',
            component: testeRouter
        }
    ]
})

Vue.createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

ERROR

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
```

The pages don't render anymore. I've been a while trying to fix it. Anyone knows what it could be? Thanks

```json
{
  "name": "routing-software",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "routing-software",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
        "core-js": "^3.8.3",
        "router": "^1.3.7",
        "vue": "^3.2.40",
        "vue-axios": "^3.4.1",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
        "vuex": "^4.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
      }
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can chain them like you did `createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')`. Maybe try to use the CLI to create a brand new app with a router and get the configuration from there.

Comment: Also, your `package.json` looks quite funky with its `"": {` part.

Comment: Hello, Kissu! How u are doing? I found the solution to my case and it is down below. Thanks for always help me ;)

Comment: Glad your issue is solved João!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue 3` does not have direct access `use` method. That's the issue.

```
Vue.use(VueRouter) // this is the issue
```

Try like this

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'

import store from './store'

import testeRouter from './pages/testeRouter'

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    routers: [
        {
            path: '/pages/testeRouter',
            component: testeRouter
        }
    ]
})

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Checkout Vue 3 route handling [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript) & Breaking changes [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#a-note-for-plugin-authors)

Comment: Should also point out that bootstrap-vue only works with `@vue/compat` starting with 2.23.0.  Also requires Bootstrap 4.x CSS and does not work with 5.x. There are likely more issues in this app than just the router config.

Comment: Yup, He has to fix them one by one 

Comment: @Naren, yes, that was the problem! You helped a lot and I also found this awser that was very useful to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620955/vue-router-cannot-read-property-foreach-of-undefined-at-createroutermatcher

Comment: @Tim, this is my first project using VueJs XD I already did what I wanted to do with router, however BootStrap still works fine.